# JS NaN comparison in switch cases

Tags: javascript, types, nan

Making a function and can`t understand how would I make a comparison in switch case, so NaN === case goes true and return "Input number is Number.NaN";

```
 function whatNumberIsIt(n){
      var str;
      switch (n) {
      case Number.MAX_VALUE : str = "Input number is Number.MAX_VALUE";
      break;
      case Number.MIN_VALUE : str = "Input number is Number.MIN_VALUE";
      break;
      case Number.NaN : str = "Input number is Number.NaN";
      break;
      case -Infinity : str = "Input number is Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY";
      break;
      case Infinity : str = "Input number is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY";
      break;
      default : str = "Input number is " + n;
      }
      return str;
    }
whatNumberIsIt(NaN)
```

Comment: You can insert an check in your default case. Using `isNaN()` you can show a different string if it's a `NaN`.

Comment: @Teemu thanks, tried this one too, but still doesn`t work(
@MohitBhardwaj in this case I need my default case for all others cases except max_value, min_value, infinity and nan etc.

Comment: @Teemu you can run a function and you will see that in your case (case !+n : str = 'Input number is NaN'; break;) it wouldn`t go for it and return default case.

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is `false` so you cannot use switch to check if a value is `NaN`

Comment: @OleksandrBuchek Indeed, my bad. Removed the comments.

Comment: @Teemu the thing is switch cases uses strong comparison and I just can`t find any way NaN === something would go true (using switch case)

Comment: @t.niese seems you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare `isNaN` in the switch statement, check for false. Here's the code:

```
  function whatNumberIsIt(n){
        var str;

        /**
         * The  !isNaN(n)  here is really the secret sauce.
         * This means the value has to be a real number before comparisons will 
         * even happen. That's why we're able to compare "false" in the switch... otherwise
         * this code wouldn't work.
         */
        switch (!isNaN(n) && n) {
            case Number.MAX_VALUE : 
                str = "Input number is Number.MAX_VALUE";
                break;

            case Number.MIN_VALUE : 
                str = "Input number is Number.MIN_VALUE";
                break;

            case false : 
                str = "Input number is Number.NaN";
                break;

            case -Infinity : 
                str = "Input number is Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY";
                break;

            case Infinity : 
                str = "Input number is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY";
                break;

            default : str = "Input number is " + n;
        }

        return str;
      }

  console.log( whatNumberIsIt("String") );
  console.log( whatNumberIsIt(NaN) );
  console.log( whatNumberIsIt(1) );
  console.log( whatNumberIsIt(Infinity) );
  console.log( whatNumberIsIt(-Infinity) );
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87o83q2q/

Here's the output you should expect:

```
Input number is Number.NaN
Input number is Number.NaN
Input number is 1
Input number is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
Input number is Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
```

Comment: I truly believed I tried false case. It works! Thanks

Comment: It's not just about false, you have to add the comparison operator to the switch statement itself. See my edited notes about the `!isNaN(n)` ... that's why this works at all. Without it, it will continue to fail.

Comment: didn`t notice before, but now I am totally confused. Could you explain me  switch (!isNaN(n) && n) and how would it work with false case?

Comment: Because when you have a row of statements, they are evaluated in order. If one fails, it stops evaluating. So if you are comparing `!isNaN(n)` .. that will return `false` for strings and anything NaN because it's a boolean comparison. If it **IS** a number, it'll continue onward through the statement to `n` and use that for the switch.